# CSS: How does Width work as a percentage?

Tags: css, width, parent

I'm having what I think is a weird problem. I have one div, inside a parent div, and I'm giving the child div a width of 100%, but it's not growing to the size of the parent div.

The parent div does **not** have a set width of any kind. So my question: does width in percentage only work when a parent element has a set width, or should it grow anyway?

CLARIFICATION:

Some may be wondering how the parent div has a width to grow to at all, if it itself does not have a set width. The reason is I have other siblings of the child element inside the parent div, with a set width to them, so the parent div has grown to meet those sibling widths.

CODE SAMPLE:

```
<div id="parent-div">
    <div id="child-element" style="width: 100%">Content</div>
    <div id="sibling" style="width: 250px"></div>
</div>
```

Child element is not growing to meet the parent div. The width of 100% is essentially not doing anything at all that I can tell. This is in IE7.

Thanks.

**FOLLOW-UP**: Thanks everyone for the answers. I'm busy testing on my end. I originally thought that parent div's only grow as wide as their children, but it turns out I was wrong given my example above, which I coded only to demonstrate my issue I'm having. In my case, my parent div has a `position: fixed` and `bottom: 1px` and `right: 1px` applied to it. From my tests, this appears to change the behavior of the parent div. No longer does it automatically stretch to the entire width of the page, but assumes the behavior I thought was the case anyway, which is the parent div expands only enough to accommodate its widest child. So that's the behavior I'm seeing now, but only because my parent div has a fixed position.

Comment: Please post the actual html and css you're using.

Comment: Could you post your code, or at least a sample of it? It's much easier to troubleshoot if you can see what you're doing...

Comment: A div is always 100% width to start with; until you float it, position it absolutely, etc.

Comment: Without the complete html and css, this question simply doesn´t make any sense and all answers are speculations. And what´s up with the upvotes?

Answer (score 2):

Without having seen the rest of your CSS and HTML, I'm going to assume that what you've posted is all there is in your HTML and CSS.

In that case:

- parent-div will definitely be as wide as the page, i.e. 100%.
- child-element will also be as wide as the page, i.e. 100%, and be inside parent-div
- sibling will have a width of 250px and be underneath child-element

If this is not the case, you've got other HTML or CSS interfering.

Comment: @thus-sprach.. without giving the parent div a width, it does not stretch to the full width of the page. It simply grows to as wide as it needs to grow to accommodate it's children. Thus the parent div, in this case, is 250px wide because of it's child with a set width. The problem is my one div with 100% that is not growing, presumably because the parent div has not been given a set width.

Comment: @thus-sprach : absolutely right, unless there are no html tags and it's rendered as text ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This screenshot explains how metrics are measured with CSS. Excuse the French, it's from my computer.

[padding, margin and border http://img524.imageshack.us/img524/5211/capturedcran20100204173.png](http://img524.imageshack.us/img524/5211/capturedcran20100204173.png)

Where "marge" means `margin`, "bordure" means `border` and "espacement" means `padding`. `Margin` falls around the `border`, which in turn falls around the `padding`, which in turns falls around the actual element size. In this example (which was taken by inspecting the stack overflow answer `<textarea>` tag) shows that there is no margin, the border is 1px wide, and there is a 3px padding between the border of the `<textarea>` and its contents; and the size the content can use, excluding the padding, is 660x200. This size matches the CSS `width` and `height` properties.

From a nested element, you can only occupy the actual element size. `Padding` on the parent will cause your nested items to keep a margin. That means there may still be space between the border of your nested  and the border of its parent.

If you want your nested `<div>` to take all the room it can, you must set its `margin` property to `0px`, and the `padding` property of its parent to `0px` as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a css trick. It goes like this:

**If you set the parent div position to relative and the child divs position to absolute then child divs will remain inside the parent div even though their position is absolute.**

See: [Absolute Positioning Inside Relative Positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) for more explanation.

Thanks

Comment: You're right that causes the width of 100% to be applied, but the absolute positioning is not practical in my particular case.

Answer (score 0):

As zneak pointed out, don't forget to **reset the css box model**; see [this great article on understanding the box model](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/).

```
#parent div {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Just to point out, don't forget to set

```
#child-element {
    display: block;
}
```

as you may have set it to **inline** an it won't expand to 100% of parent's width.

I couldn't replicate your problem, everything worked just fine.